# How to avoid PessimisticLockException for overlapping "Email Queue Send" jobs using Spring @Transactional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a email queue send job that runs every minute, but am running into `PessimisticLockException` issues sometimes when jobs overlap (i.e. a job takes more than 60 seconds to complete). I am able to reproduce this in a test, but I can't seem to solve the issue. The general logic is below.

Clearly, in my attempt to use Transaction `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` for saving entities "immediately" to the database, I am causing issues elsewhere, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct logic on this.

It's worth noting that if I "detach" each EmailQueue entity from inside the "send email loop", then I avoid the `PessimisticLockException`. However when I do this, 3 emails are sent instead of 2 (the `emailQueueService.findQueued(onOrBefore)` correctly returns 1 email on the first job, but returns 2 emails on the overlapping job - erroneously returning the previous "SENT" email)

```
JAVA
public void sendQueuedEmails(Instant onOrBefore) {

    // Fetches EmailQueue.State = "QUEUED" and EmailQueue.ScheduledSendDateTime <= onOrBefore
    // !! ISSUE :: On overlapping job, this also returns emails marked "SENT"
    List<EmailQueue> emailQueueList = emailQueueService.findQueued(onOrBefore);

    // Change EmailQueue.State = "SENDING" in separate @Transaction so they don't get picked up again by overlapping job
    // Uses @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    emailQueueService.markEmailQueuesAsSending(emailQueueList);

    // Send email loop
    for (EmailQueue emailQueue : emailQueueList) {

        // Send EmailQueue
        // Changes EmailQueue.State = "SENT" (no database calls made in this method)
        appUserEmailSender.send(emailQueue);

        // Save EmailQueue
        // Uses @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        emailQueueService.saveAndCommit(emailQueue);

        // !! ISSUE :: Without this statement a PessimisticLockException will be thrown when calling "markEmailQueuesAsSending()" on overlapping job
        // emailQueueService.detach(emailQueue);
    }
}
```

And my test method looks like this:

```
@Test
void sendQueuedEmails_overlapping_jobs() throws Exception {

    // Load 2 Emails, 1 scheduled to be sent at 1am, 1 scheduled to be sent at 2am
    helper.loadData("com/afs/core/service/email/EmailQueueSenderImplTest.xml", "db/testData.dtd", DatabaseOperation.INSERT);

    Instant scheduledSendDateTime_1 = // 1 am
    Instant scheduledSendDateTime_2 = // 2 am

    // half second delay each time myMailSenderMock.send() is called
    doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(500, invocation -> null))
            .when(myMailSenderMock).send();

    // When calling overlapping sendQueuedEmails
    emailQueueSender.sendQueuedEmails(scheduledSendDateTime_1);
    emailQueueSender.sendQueuedEmails(scheduledSendDateTime_2);

    // Then 2 emails should be sent successfully
    Mockito.verify(myMailSenderMock, Mockito.times(2)).send();
}
```

In case this helps, my @Transactional methods are:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void markEmailQueuesAsSending(List<EmailQueue> emailQueueList) {
    for (EmailQueue emailQueue : emailQueueList) {
        emailQueue.setEmailQueueState(EmailQueueState.SENDING);
        this.save(emailQueue);
    }
    this.flush();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveAndCommit(EmailQueue instance) {
    save(instance);
    this.flush();
}
```